# Why does Carbon Menu Manager work in a 64-bit Cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, 64-bit, macos-carbon

I have a 64-bit Cocoa application that for legacy reasons calls Carbon function `CancelMenuTracking` to close an open menu. `CancelMenuTracking` is loaded *dynamically* from the `com.apple.Carbon` bundle.

The question is, why does it work (on macOS 10.14.4)? Pretty much all Carbon Menu Manager functions were documented as not available on 64-bit, before that documentation was removed.

Comment: please post com.apple.Carbon location so I can see it in hopper

Comment: @MarekH menu functions come from HIToolbox subframework, `/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework`.

Comment: lipo -info /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/HIToolbox 
Architectures in the fat file: /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/HIToolbox are: i386 x86_64 -> It's compliled for both versions 32 bit and 64 bit but I didn't compare if they have identical call table (name functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the simple answer is there's still bits of Carbon used internally in the frameworks — menus are definitely one of those areas — but that's an implementation detail and you can consider it a private API which shouldn't be used, just like CGS and others.